# Devise with Nested Address (Everything Seems to Work Except Index/Show)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

There's probably a simple way this is more of me wanting to learn through practice.

I'm nesting addresses behind devise users while putting everything (except user) in a folder called client, it all seems to work (new/create) except for the index & show actions/screens cause an error.

I had tried lots of variations including throwing client in with the mix but I don't think that's the problem.

Error that it Causes (Am I missing a through relationship?)
NameError (uninitialized constant User::Address)

client/address.rb

```
class Client::Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Devise Settings
    # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

    # Model Relationships
    has_many :addresses

end
```

client.rb

```
module Client


    # Add Prefix to Table
    def self.table_name_prefix
        'client_'
    end

end
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

    # Security Devise Setup
    devise_for :admins
    devise_for :users

    # Main Pages
    root 'website/page#index'

    # Client Sections
    resources :users do
        scope module: "client" do
            root :to => 'dashboard#index'
            resources :addresses
        end
    end

    namespace :admin do
        root :to => 'panel#index'
    end

end
```

client/addresses_controller.rb

```
class Client::AddressesController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_address, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # Index
    def index
    user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @addresses = user.addresses
    end

    # GET /client/addresses/1
    def show
    end

    # GET /client/addresses/new
    def new
        @address = Client::Address.new
    end

    # GET /client/addresses/1/edit
    def edit
    end

    # POST /client/addresses
    def create
        @address = Client::Address.new(address_params)

        if @address.save
            redirect_to user_addresses_path, notice: 'Address was successfully created.'
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /client/addresses/1
    def update
        if @address.update(address_params)
            redirect_to user_addresses_path, notice: 'Address was successfully updated.'
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    # DELETE /client/addresses/1
    def destroy
        @address.destroy
            redirect_to user_addresses_path, notice: 'Address was successfully destroyed.'
    end

    private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_address
        @address = Client::Address.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def address_params
    params.require(:client_address).permit(:cacompanyname, :caaddressline1, :caaddressline2, :cacity, :caprovince, :capostalcode, :user_id)
    end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<h1>Listing Client Addresses</h1>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Company Name</th>
            <th>Address Line 1</th>
            <th>Address Line 2</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Province</th>
            <th>PostalCode</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <% @addresses.each do |address| %>
            <tr>
                <td><%= address.cacompanyname %></td>
                <td><%= address.caaddressline1 %></td>
                <td><%= address.caaddressline2 %></td>
                <td><%= address.cacity %></td>
                <td><%= address.caprovince %></td>
                <td><%= address.capostalcode %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Show', user_address_path %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_user_address_path(user_address) %></td>
                <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', user_address, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
            </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
<%= link_to 'Add a New Address', new_user_address_path %>
```

Comment: What is the error? Please post it in the question.

Comment: Oh sorry knew I forgot something give me a min.

Comment: Posted error and addition models at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> NameError (uninitialized constant User::Address)

You need to explicitly define the `class_name` to tell ***Rails*** to use this, else it will look for the class `Address` which isn't there.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  # Model Relationships
  has_many :addresses, class_name: 'Client::Address'
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Just give me a second to test it and I'll give you credit.